# How can I stop my dog from barking when placed in outside pen?

Tags: dogs, behavior, vocalizations

My dog is placed in outside pen daily. It is a large pen with room to run. She has plenty of water and toys. She barks non stop for hours on in. How can I stop the barking? I hate the neighbors have to hear the incessant barking.

Comment: What breed of dog please? What is a large pen - estimate of size please?

Answer (score 1):

Your dog might want some company and may want to play with you or want to go on a walk. Dogs have feelings and he probably doesn't like it that he is alone a lot of the time. Even if she has toys try and at least take her out of the park and maybe make her catch a ball or something that will make her better.

Answer (score 0):

I always am outside with my dogs. If they bark, I tell them to leave it. If they continue I spray off a can of keyboard cleaner. They hate the noise. It startles them. My English bulldog is the only barker I got. The other two just don’t care about what’s going on. Probably because I don’t leave them out without me out there.